# Error with modal and JS - Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so i am trying to do this modal however i am getting this error when i try to use the button, i am not sure if the is how it is done as this is my first time using js and i have been following tutorials. Thank you for the help.

ERROR {
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 67,
"colno": 21
}

```js
const open = document.getElementById('open');
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
const close = document.getElementById('close');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal_container.classList.add('show');
});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal_container.classList.remove('show');
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: crimson;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.modal-container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
}
.modal-container .show {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.modal p {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
 <button id="open">Introduction</button>
  <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
      <div class="modal">
          <h1>Introduction</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta pariatur ut, veniam illum nemo repellat explicabo dignissimos ex ipsum aliquid.</p>
          <button id="close">Click here to close.</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Typo. Your class has a dash but you are querying with an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

```
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
```

change to:

```
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal-container');
```

Answer (score 3):

Your id is `modal-container` not `modal_container`

```
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal-container');
```

**EDIT**:
Make sure your CSS selector is right, it should be without space if the classes are on same element and not the children.

```
.modal-container.show
```

Comment: I have updated the code